# Check if oracle password is expired/invalid via OCI8 PHP

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

Is there a way to check if Oracle Database password is expired or invalid using OCI8 in a PHP file without locking the DB user for invalid attempt? (PS: My database user gets locked after 3 invalid attempts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you connect to Oracle database as a privileged user (such as SYS) and check DBA_USERS:

```
SQL> desc dba_users;
 Name
 --------------------------------
 USERNAME
 USER_ID
 PASSWORD
 ACCOUNT_STATUS
 LOCK_DATE
 EXPIRY_DATE               --> this
 DEFAULT_TABLESPACE
 TEMPORARY_TABLESPACE
 CREATED
 PROFILE
 INITIAL_RSRC_CONSUMER_GROUP
 EXTERNAL_NAME
 PASSWORD_VERSIONS
 EDITIONS_ENABLED
 AUTHENTICATION_TYPE

SQL>
```

you'll see the EXPIRY_DATE so - check that value.

As of "invalid password": I think that you don't have to worry about it as Oracle won't let you store an invalid password anyway.

Comment: What if i don't have Sys access? I want to use oci_connect to login and if the password is invalid and i try this 3 time will it lock the user on DB?

Comment: It doesn't have to be SYS. Ask DBA to grant you access to that view (probably indirectly). I'm not sure that you can get that info somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot. Could you please tell me if giving invalid username and password in an oci_connect function will lock the DB user i am trying to access?

Comment: It might, as far as I can tell. Just as any other "source" of connection (Forms, SQL*Plus, ...)

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot 